# Multiproccess Pool irregular behavior when processing from queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a script that parses a large text file (~5.5GB) of irregularly sized records and sends each record to a JoinableQueue, `tasks`. These tasks are handled by a pool of workers who them put results into another JoinableQueue, `results`. My problem arises when trying to process this queue with another pool of workers concurrently. Here is a small example of what I have currently.

```
def process_nodes(results_queue, return_dict):
    while True:
        node_pairs = results_queue.get()
        results_queue.task_done()
        if node_pairs is None:
            results_queue.task_done()
            break
        for key in node_pairs:
            return_dict[tuple(key)] += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_workers = mp.cpu_count() * 2
    tasks = mp.JoinableQueue()
    results = mp.JoinableQueue()
    parser = ParseVehicleTrajectories('VehTrajectory_1.dat', tasks)
    task_workers = [TaskWorker(tasks, results) for i in range(num_workers - 2)]
    for worker in task_workers:
        worker.start()
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    return_dict = manager.defaultdict(int)
    results_worker = mp.Process(target=process_nodes, args=(results, return_dict))
    results_worker.start()
    parser.run()
    for _ in range(num_workers - 2):
        tasks.put(None)
    results.put(None)
    tasks.join()
    print(len(return_dict), sum(return_dict.values()))
```

`ParseVehicleTrajectories` is the class that reads the file and pushes records onto the queue. `TaskWorker` is the worker class and inherits from `mp.Process`.

My issue is that sometimes this code will run properly and print results and other times it does not. When it does not it appears that `results` is not exhausted yet and the `results_worker` is stopped. I admit that I am not a master of multiprocessing so it is possible I have missed something obvious, but I have been through SO exhaustively and can't find a solution.